# AsyncSeq not printing to Console in Interactive

Tags: asynchronous, f#, f#-interactive

I have defined a simple record type

```
type RowSapPL = { CargoID: int; Currency: string; IsInternal: bool; Amount: decimal}
```

Everything is ok, also from the db point of view (I see the expected records in the table) but I can't read the messages (`"*** Ok ... "`) of the `action` in the Console of F# Interactive in Visual Studio.
I've also tried with `AsyncSeq.iter` instead of `AsyncSeq.iterAsync` and the synchronous version of `action`.
What am I missing? Only `"starting async seq"` and `"async seq ended"` and the sql logging (from a trivial `SqlQueryEvent |> Event.add` not shown above) are printed from the async computation expression.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `yield` instead of `return` in my `asyncSeq` functions to empty and insert rows in the table.